# Text getting cleared when using TextEditingController and StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

I have observed some strange behaviour when using `TextEditingController` and `FocusNode` in combination with `StreamBuilder`, namely:

- `Text` inside a `TextField` getting cleared when unselecting the text field
- Two input carets being active at the same time on two separate text fields

This happens when all the following conditions are met:

- A stateless widget creates its own `TextEditingControllers` and `FocusNodes`.
- These are used within some `TextField` widgets.
- The stateless widget's build method returns a `StreamBuilder`, which rebuilds the widget contents (including the `TextFields`) when new values are pushed to the stream.
- The stateless widget is presented as a MaterialPageRoute.

**NOTE:** if the stateless widget is not presented, but is presented directly when the app starts, the issue does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on my end. The issue was that I was persisting objects inside a `StatelessWidget`.

You shouldn't.

Opening the keyboard tends to rebuild the whole screen (which is fine). But in my case rebuilding cause your `TextEditingController` to be GCed because you stored them inside a `StatelessWidget`

So the reason that this works with `StatefulWidget` is that the state is retained even across rebuilds, so I can use it to hold my `TextEditingControllers`.